# Split a string returned from a column into integers

Tags: sql, casting

Let me explain... I have one table which has a column that contains a delimited list of numbers which need to be used to return data from another table. (Don't ask, I did not design this!). EG:

```
Set @DelimitedList = (Select stupid_column from Table_One)
```

This results in @DelimitedList containing '1,2,3'; I then want to use this in a 'Where' clause for a subsequent query... i.e

```
Select * from Table_Two where int_column in (@DelimitedList)
```

Sadly this does not work as SQL tries to convert @DelimitedList to an integer which fails.
Is there some way I can 'cast' or 'convert' my string list into an integer array?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split string in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)

Comment: Is this MS-SQL? Can you do it in the application layer with two statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done following way:
Replace

```
WHERE    int_column in (@DelimitedList)
```

with

```
WHERE    ','+@DelimitedList+',' LIKE '%,'+CAST(int_column AS Varchar(10))+',%'
```

Also it can depend on your RDBMS. For example in MySQL you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Answer (score 2):

Using dynamic SQL, which I do not necessarily recommend, you may be able to do as follows:

```
EXEC ('Select * from Table_Two where int_column in (' + @DelimitedList + ')')
```

You can find more info, [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html).

Comment: Thanks Thejaka, this does work but I think I favour valex's version below. I did try EXEC but got it all wrong so your solution has cleared up how I could have done it and will be useful in the future.